# Add parenthesis to vim string

Tags: string, unix, vim, parentheses

I'm having a bit of trouble using parenthesis in a vim string. I just need to add a set of parenthesis around 3 digits, but I can't seem to find where I'm suppose to correctly place them. So for example; I would have to place them around a phone number such as: `2015551212`.

Right now I have a strings that separates the numbers and puts a hyphen between them. For example;  `201 555-1212`. So I just need the parenthesis. The final result should look like: `(201) 555-1212`

The string I have so far is this: `s/\(\d\{3}\)\(\d\{3}\)/\1 \2-/g`

How might I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the parens around the \1 in your replacement.

```
s/\(\d\{3\}\)\(\d\{3\}\)/(\1) \2-/g
```

If you want to go in reverse, and change "(800) 555-1212" to "8005551212", you can use something like this:

```
s/(\(\d\d\d\))\ \(\d\d\d\)-\(\d\d\d\d\)/\1\2\3/g
```

Instead of the `\d\d\d`, you could use `\d\{3\}`, but that is more trouble to type.

Comment: Thanks a lot that seem to have done the trick. I was also curious to know how might someone could go about reversing the process. So, instead of using s/\(\d\{3\}\)\(\d\{3\}\)/(\1) \2-/g to get: (201) 555-1212. Could you simply remove the parens, space,and hyphen like this? s/\(\d\{3\}\)\(\d\{3\}\)/\1\2/g

Comment: @ehstudent to remove parenthesis/dash etc. you don't need so complex command, just `:s/\D//g`

Comment: Glad it worked for you. You might consider [accepting my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Kent's suggestion will work for reversing the process, if your file only has phone numbers in it. It removes all non-digit characters.

Comment: @Markku K That is true while Kents suggestion is helpful unfortunately it would only work for the the entire file contains only numbers/digits. I have a file that contains both characters and digits. So, I'm not to clear how to reverse the process with using a complex string.

Comment: @ Markku K I tried the command that you had revised in your answer and it works great. Personally think that while using \d\{3\} saves time or compacts it, using \d\d\d seems like an easier layout. Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.